# React Router & Link: It does not respect search parameters (or so I think)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, react-router-dom

I am creating my own mini blog, and am implementing search functionality.

I use Strapi, a headless CMS. So if I want to search for specific posts, I can add a `?_q=search here` to the API call to query for those posts.

In my React app, I have a `Posts` component that forwards the URL in the page to the API which can easily be done with `window.location.pathname + window.location.search`. So if someone goes to `https://exampleblog.com/posts?_q=search here` then React will take the pathname and search parameters and use it for the API call to Strapi. I do this because it saves a lot of work.

With my search functionality, I use a `Link` component from `react-router-dom` as the search button. There is state that takes the value from a text box, and changes the value of the `to` property in the `Link` component so that `to` can look like `/posts?_q=textbox value`. And because the pathname and search parameters from the page are forwarded to the API, it should resolve the right posts.

My problem is that if the pathname in the URL changes (for example `/posts` goes to something like `/categories`), the `Link` component renders the page (which is right). **However**, if only the `search` parameter changes (the `?_q=search here` in the URL) then the URL in the browser changes, but nothing new renders.

I would also like to add that the search 100% works when searching from a page with a different pathname, so the search parameters are functional. But if I perform the search on the page with the same pathname, then it does not.

From my observations, I am making the conclusion that the `Link` component does not respect changes to the search parameters in the URL.

Below is some example code.

Snippet from `Posts` component:

```
const pathname = window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
const {loading, error, data} = useApi(pathname); // Custom hook to resolve API requests. Already knows the hostname.
// Continued code in this component will render the API result
```

The whole of `Search` component:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Search() {
    const [query, setQuery] = useState('');

    return (
        <div className="search">
            <label>Search</label>
            <input type="text" onChange={event => setQuery(event.target.value)}></input>
            <Link to={`/posts?_q=${query}`} className="button">
                Search
            </Link>
        </div>
    );
}
```

My "useApi" custom hook:

```
export default function useApi(endpoint = '/') {
    const URI = process.env.URI;

    const [state, setState] = useState({
        loading: true,
        error: false,
        data: null
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios.get(URI + endpoint);
                const data = response.data;

                setState({
                    loading: false,
                    error: false,
                    data
                });
            } catch (error) {
                setState({
                    loading: false,
                    error: true,
                    data: null
                });
            }
        })();
    }, [endpoint]);

    return state;
}
```

As you can see, the endpoint argument provided to the useApi hook will eventually be `window.location.pathname + window.location.search`, which means it will track the necessary changes including the changing value of the search parameter.

Any help, as usual, will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found another solution to my own problem!

I am still a believer in my reasoning for why it did not work. However, there is a more official workaround built in to React Router V6. I have not tested this on earlier versions.

You can use the `useSearchParams` hook built into `react-router-dom`/`react-router`.

In the following example, "?page=" will be defined as a search parameter:

```
export default function Component() {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams({});
  const searchObject = Object.fromEntries(searchParams.entries());
  const { page } = searchObject;
  const pageInt = parseInt(page);

  return (
    <a onClick={() => {
        e.preventDefault(); // To avoid a complete page load.
        setSearchParams({ ...searchObject, page: `${pageInt + 1}` }
    }}>Update search</a>
  );
}
```

The above code is a highly simplified version of what I managed to achieve so feel free to optimise. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:**
When the query parameters change the component does not re-renders so the API is not called again.

**Solution:**
You should call the API in a useEffect() hook with the query parameter in the dependency array so that whenever the query parameter changes the API will be called with the new query parameters.

Comment: Hi Zohaib, thanks a lot for the response. I already track the right values in the dependency array. I am going to edit my original question to include the useApi custom hook I made.